# Contain Write-host in a variable

Tags: powershell

I am after storing write-host as a variable for multiple lines

So I want to encompass the write-host section below so it is essentially copied and pasted to the beginning of the loop, updating certain parameters.

the script is to check a file and see how many lines are in the file, this then carries out a function on each line, I want to update the user on the progress, however during the loop I cls and want to update the progress. Simple progress bar.

However I am unable to do so, so I created a variable that stores this information and updates accordingly.~

The varible only contains the information I want to update, see code.

I have tried the following;

Surrounding in parenthese, 
using , to change to a new line,
Encasing the statement in ().

```
$56 = (Write-Host "This is a test" -foregroundcolor green),
(Write-host "Same Test only bigger"-foregroundcolor red) , 
"No!",
"I am King" $King ++
#$56
```

Output is

```
This is a test
Same Test only bigger
```

I want it to only display if I use the variable $56 as you can see it pulls the write-host without the variable.

Comment: To store commands as strings and execute later, you should probably check out [Invoke-Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-6).  However, this is [not a recommended practice](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingInvokeExpression.md) and you should probably re-factor your code to avoid it.  Write-Host is also [frowned upon](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSScriptAnalyzer/blob/development/RuleDocumentation/AvoidUsingWriteHost.md).

Comment: If you _insist_ on using `Write-Host` (*I am in full agreement with @boxdog on this point*), you might want to consider a script block instead of an array; a script block stored as a variable can then be invoked as `& $scriptblockvar`. But it's still not a good idea.

Comment: I may have a look at script block, however it does mean starting again with my script.

Comment: You may want to explain what you're trying to do in more detail, as you're likely going about it the wrong way. When a few of the experienced members here are commenting that what you're doing is a bad idea, it normally is. You might just be approaching it in a way that powershell specifically doesn't deal with if you're used to a different language.

Answer (score 0):

I still think a function can do this:

```
function Output {

param([int]$lineNumber)

switch ($lineNumber) {

    1 {Write-Host "This is a test" -foregroundcolor green}
    2 {Write-host "Same Test only bigger"-foregroundcolor red}
    3 {"No!"}
    4 {"I am King"}
}

}

PS H:\> Output 1
This is a test

PS H:\> Output 4
I am King
```

I don't know what King is here, but if you want to use that as an increment, then you can just do this:

```
PS H:\> $King = 1

PS H:\> Output $King
This is a test

PS H:\> $King++

PS H:\> output $King
Same Test only bigger
```

Comment: The probelm with the function is that it won't get update the information so for example, if king was followed by $King which incremented after each loop then in the function it would not update and still show as 1 and not the true number such as 34.

Comment: @bob500000 `if king was followed by $King which incremented` Your code sample and explanation make close to no sense at all.

Comment: @notjustme, Sorry I have updated the question to reflect this;

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Host` doesn't return its output as an object; it bypasses the pipeline to go directly to the console, effectively "returning" a null string. As such, you can't save the result of a `Write-Host` in a variable.

You can, however, save a script block in a variable, and execution of any statement in the script block variable will be deferred until the variable is invoked with the `&` expression, e.g.,

```
$fifty-six = { Write-Host "This is a test" -foregroundcolor green }
& $fifty-six
```

You should, however, consider carefully what your goal is, and whether there might not be a better way to do things. If you are interested in tracking the progress of a function, and you are using PowerShell 3.0 or later, you may want to look into [`Write-Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-6) instead.

Comment: I already have processes in place to collect the data, so not really bothered about storting it, however in the example I want to include all of the text in the varible, changing certain colours depending on the result.

so "this text would be green", "this text would be yellow" etc. "2 would be red" when I update the "2" to the next value "3" it stays red.

this is where it gets interesting, as far as I know changing the colour of multiple lines in a variable is not an option.